# Sending an email to a user to open a specific url in django

Tags: django

I am developing a Django Application right now. I have a signup and login feature setup on my site. My website currently has a "special" group of users that would require to access an additional page. This page, for design reasons, should only be accessed by that specific user. I wouldn't want to have that URL be public and be accessed by merely typing it in the browser (Very similar to a password reset design). How do I go about doing this, considering that I would want to send an email with the link?

Would this involve a token authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can type any URL in the browser.  You have to authorize on your end.  You can test for the user in the view:

```
if request.user.is_active:
    if request.user.username == "good_user":
        #OK to access
    else:
        #serve "not authorized" message
else:
    #redirect to login
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. I am trying to send them a tokenized URL in which another person just can't type and get in. This is how the password reset works in Django. I wanted a similar structure for my application

Comment: Do you mean you are sending it to visitor who is not a logged-in user?

Comment: Yeah. For instance, User A is created in the database. I want to send an email to User A, asking them to click on the link and continue filling this up. I am doing this because of the constraints I am working around. Obviously, I don't want an anonymous user to be accessing the link User A is. That's why I am trying to see if I can use a token or similar

Comment: I don't need it to be a password reset, but I want to use that kind of design for this and other places in my application. Such as accessing specific pages and such

Comment: For a single user or group of users?

Comment: For a single user.

Comment: So, you could make a random token and store it in the User, then test for it in the view: `if request.user.random_token == "Jj7hH7g7ub*&g8h8":`